# Port Scanner written in python does not display output normally

Tags: python, python-3.x, port

So I tried to write a port scanner in `python3`
Here is my code:

```
import sys #allows us to enter command line arguments, among other things
import socket
from datetime import datetime

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    target = socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[1]) #Translate a hostname to IPv4
else:
    print("Invalid amount of arguments.")
    print("Syntax: python3 scanner.py <ip>")
    sys.exit()

#Add a banner
print("-" * 50)
print("Scanning target "+target)
print("Time started: "+str(datetime.now()))
print("-" * 50)
try:
    for port in range(50,85):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
        result = s.connect_ex((target,port)) #returns error indicator
        print("Checking port {}".format(port))
        if result == 0:
            print("Port {} is open".format(port))
        s.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nExiting program.")
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print("Hostname could not be resolved.")
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print("Couldn't connect to server.")
    sys.exit()
```

using Kali Linux 2020.2, with the newest version of python,

I executes `python3 scanner.py google.com`

It is expected that the scanner will display "Checking port 50", "Checking port 51" one by one during the scanning process.

And if it find any one of the ports is open, it shows "Port xx is open" after the "Checking port xx"

However, my scanner was stuck as the initial banner.

And eventually when it has completed the scanning, it displays all the output in one go.

Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: When running your code the behavior i see is exactly what you wanted to happen so i dont see an issue in your code. is your OS maybe buffering the output?

Comment: maybe try your prints with `flush=True` like `print("Checking port {}".format(port), flush=True)` just to rule out any bugffering and force the buffer to flush on each print command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch the following lines in your code:

```py
result = s.connect_ex((target,port)) #returns error indicator
print("Checking port {}".format(port))
```

becomes:

```py
print("Checking port {}".format(port))
result = s.connect_ex((target,port)) #returns error indicator
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply!. OK, that's exactly what I want. But something really strange happened. It shows Checking port 50 initially, and just stuck. But after like one minute or two, it starts like really "scanning" one by one. I am wondering is that the fault of my machine lead to the stuck of the long wating time for scanning port 50? Thanks

Comment: @MakMingHei I don't think your machine causes the delay but rather the remote machine. Try to scan different remote machines, even some IPs on your local network. You would probably notice different response times.